# Can you reference Azure Key Vault secrets inside application.properties?

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-keyvault

I have a record:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("service.api")
@ConstructorBinding
public record ServiceApiConfig(String clientId, String clientSecret) {}
```

and an application.properties file:

```
service.api.client_id=client_id
service.api.client_secret=client_secret
```

and the binding works when I'm doing local development.

What I want to do is to use Azure services (Azure Spring Apps, Key Vault, etc.) and my question is whether I can, inside application.properties file, reference secrets stored in the Key Vault. Something like this:

```
service.api.client_id=<name-of-the-id-kept-in-the-vault>
service.api.client_secret=<name-of-the-secret-kept-in-the-vault>
```

Tutorials I've seen make me think that the only way to do the binding is by using `@Value("${nameOfTheSecret}")` annotation on fields in java classes. Is it possible to do it in a way that I want?

Comment: One option could be to use Azure Key Vault Reference (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli) and then add the following in .properties file: ${yourEnvVariableName}

Answer (score 0):

You can reference Azure Key Vault secrets inside the `application.properties` file by adding the below properties of azure key vault which you want to connect from the spring boot application:

```
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].credential.client-id=<your client ID>
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].credential.client-secret=<your client key>
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].endpoint=https://contosokv.vault.azure.net/
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].profile.tenant-id=<your tenant ID>
```

Comment: And how do I reference them after adding these lines?

Comment: for complete steps, check out this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-key-vault)